# Какие существуют "события"?

Tags: java, windows, события

**Большинство событий**, на которые реагирует прикладная программа
с графическим пользовательским интерфейсом, происходят **при взаимодействии пользователя с этой программой**.

Какие существуют **еще события**?

**update**

- Операционная система `Windows`
- Язык программирования `Java`
- `Windows API`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Начал писать коммент, но вышел за рамки и решил опубликовать как ответ.

[Событие](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) весьма распространенный шаблон ООП.

> Событие в объектно-ориентированном программировании — это сообщение, которое возникает в различных точках исполняемого кода при выполнении определённых условий.
>   События предназначены для того, чтобы иметь возможность предусмотреть реакцию программного обеспечения

Соответственно, классы-события разработчики могут определять по собственному усмотрению в любых ситуациях когда требуется реагировать на изменения состояния объектов извне.

Список событий в любом ОО-языке (как минимум) будет бесконечен.

Вопрос, тем не менее, может иметь смысл для стандартных событий в конкретной библиотеке графических компонентов. Проблема в том, что как для Windows так и для Java существует множество популярных платформ разработки интерфейса каждая со своим набором событий.

Например (и это только для десктопа):

- для Windows: Win32, Winforms, WPF;
- для Java: AWT, Swing, Java FX.

В качестве общего подхода могу предложить:

- определиться с платформой/библиотекой ;
- найти для платформы/библиотеки базовый класс событий (`Event`, `Listener`);
- либо найти определенное событие и проверить от какого класса он наследуется.

Например:

- для Java Swing: посмотрите на пакет [javax.swing.event](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/package-summary.html)
- для .Net: можно начать с урока [Events and Delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17sde2xt(v=VS.100).aspx) на MSDN, либо поискать события определенные для каждого класса (например [Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form_events(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: Хороший ответ. Если добавить краткое определение события, то он, думаю, ещё лучше станет. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin добавил, спасибо)

Comment: @TimurVi премного благодарен за вознаграждение. Рад, если получилось чем то помочь.

Answer (score 6):

Вопрос слишком общий. События можно разделить по многим категориям, многие из которых во многом пересекаются.

Например:

- Внешние, порожденные "снаружи" рабочей станции (обычно это сеть).
- Внутренние, порожденные "на рабочей станции" (разнообразные устройства ввода).
- Внутренние, порожденные "внутри" рабочей станции (таймеры, другие приложения)

Для вашего приложения, события могут быть:

- вызваны штатной работой вашей программы (вы сами создаете и отправляете события внутри)
- предоставлены / обернуты фреймворком (пользовательский ввод, стандартные события ОС)
- событиями на которые вы подпишитесь (в обход фреймворка)

Answer (score 5):

Выскажу слегка парадоксальную мысль.

Ваше наблюдение:

> Большинство **событий**, на которые реагирует прикладная программа с графическим пользовательским интерфейсом, происходят при взаимодействии пользователя с этой программой.

Является чуточку ложным, поскольку это как раз **события** в рамках концепции [Event-Driven-Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) - *событийно-ориентированное программирование*. Именно для GUI и была в свое время разработана эта концепция (70-е годы наверное), хотя легко можно представить и другую реализацию GUI, где ее можно реализовать без *событий*.

В рамках расширенного толкования [Event-Driven-Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming), событием можно сделать практически все что угодно. Есть различные фреймворки, в терминах, которых почти все что угодно может порождать события.

Например: завершение работы какого-либо метода легко может порождать событие, которое встраивается в общую схему обработки событий в виде `MyMessage` - сообщения об его завершении:

```
public void myMethod(int myParameter) {
     //blah-blah
     MyEventManager.triggerEvent(this, new MyMessage("bye!"));
}
```

Где есть некий слушатель событий `MyEventManager`, далее обрабатывающий посланное сообщение и перенаправляющий поток программы куда следует.

Ну и т.д. В общем все зависит от пожеланий программиста.

Естественно существуют и недостатки таковой системы, одним из главных недостатков является низкая портабельность кода и несоответствие парадигме: *write once, use everywhere*

Answer (score 3):

[Источник](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31249554/)

> События могут происходить не только в результате прямого взаимодействия
>   с пользовательским интерфейсом. Например, событие может произойти по истечении
>   времени срабатывания таймера, а также в результате превышения счетчиком некоторого значения , программного или аппаратного сбоя или завершения
>   некоторой операции. Имеется возможность определять и собственные события,
>   отвечающие характеру прикладной программы.

Comment: А как же внешние события с оборудования, сети?

Answer (score 3):

Относительно неплохо систематизированы события модели [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp). Можно увидеть как события интерфейса, так и окружения. Подобную схему можно взять за основу "понимания событий"

События - элемент объектно-ориентированной парадигмы (ООП). Это оргомный пласт "чего-то особенного", что сложно объяснить словами другой парадигмы. Я бы попробовал классифицировать события так:

а) внешние / внутренние  -  по каналу поступления в объект (как например, выброс исключения-ошибки можно считать чисто внутренним событием, а действия пользователя - внешним)

б) активные / пассивные  -  по действию, ожидаемому от события (тикает таймер - ну и ладно, а вот на событие создания или удаления элементов игнорировать нельзя)

в) стандартные / самодельные  - по уровню стандартизации. При построении своих ООП проектов приходится разрабатывать свою систему сообщений (событий).

г) обрабатываемые / нет  -  по наличию обработчика события (таблицы отклика, RESPONSE TABLE). Некотрые события могут уходить "в песок", некоторые - на обработчик по умолчанию, некоторые - на заданный функционал

д) параметрические / нет  -  по наличию дополнительных параметров. Событие refresh может не содержать параметров, а pause - содержать временной интервал

*Вопрос событий действительно совсем непростой. Если еще припомнить прерывания... Тут на вполне приличную книгу хватит писанины. В рамках мини-квеста ограничусь вышеизложенными фрагментарными мыслями. Как и предыдущие авторы отмечу, что это лишь малая часть того, что хочется сказать...*